# How to upgrade from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 using sudo do-release-upgrade?

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, upgrade, update-manager

Whenever I try to upgrade I get the following errors.

> http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jessie/main/binary-i386/Packages 
>   404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]  , E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or  old ones used instead.

Then I try command-line to get the new upgrade:

`sudo do-release-upgrade`

Then I get the above error message.

Comment: That huge update step is as far I know not possible. actually it tries to update to 14.10 when you do a `do-release-upgrade`. Best way to do this upgrade is to get a disk image and do it this way.

Comment: So basically backup everything in `/` and then install ubuntu 16 over ubuntu 14, is that what you suggest?

Comment: Well not basically backup all in `/`, I usually do a backup of `/etc/` for the case I want to read up on my settings there later on and of course my `home`. But yes you got the idea right with installing over. A fresh start from time to time is not bad at all. you loose a lot of bloat this way.